# Find an integer followed by a string with Golang regexp

Tags: regex, go

I want to find an integer which is followed by the term "Price: ", whether in the output, I only need to print the integer which must be excluded the term "Price: ".
Right now, my code is like this and the output is [Price: 100], but I only need 100 in the output.

```
package main 

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

const str = "Some strings. Price: 100$. Some strings123"

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("Price:[[:space:]][0-9]+")
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(str, -1))
}
```

Comment: You say you want to find an integer followed by "Price", but your example only shows a number proceeded by "Price".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a capturing group around the number pattern and call [`re.FindStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch):

```
package main 

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

const str = "Some strings. Price: 100$. Some strings123"

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`Price:\s*(\d+)`)
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    if match != nil {
        fmt.Println(match[1])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No match!")
    }
}
```

Note that `` `Price:\s*(\d+)` `` is a raw string literal where you do not have to extra-escape backslashes that form regex escapes, so `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces and `(\d+)` matches and captures 1+ digits into Group 1 in this pattern string literal.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use next regexp:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`Price:[[:space:]]([0-9]+)`)
matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
```

The only difference - is parentheses around `[0-9]`, now you can access 100 by: `matches[1]`.

Also you can replace:

`[[:space:]]` with `\s`

`[0-9]` with `\d`

 so your regex will look simpler, like: `Price:\s(\d+)`